# How to change background image seamlessly without blink?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several continuous images that act as the background image of a div.

Supposed that these images are the water in a bottle with different water level, and I want to change these images one by one so that it looks like the water raises slowly.

And I put the images in several CSS classes and when changing the images:

```
.waterLevel1 {
    background: url(path/to/my/image);
}
```

I used the code that similar to the follows:

```
$('#myDiv').addClass('waterLevel2').removeClass('waterLevel1');
```

It do worked for changing images, however, there was sometimes a blink between the changes.

Is there any way to avoid the blinks?

**UPDATE**

The images are already gif pictures, so just replacing them is ok.

I do not have those pictures right now, sorry for the jsfiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle will be much appreciated !

Comment: preload the background image first.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to use several `divs`. Then just change the display's

```
<div class="waterLevelWrapper">
    <div class="waterLevel waterLevel1" style="display:block;"></div>
    <div class="waterLevel waterLevel2" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="waterLevel waterLevel3" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="waterLevel waterLevel4" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="waterLevel waterLevel5" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Make `.waterLevelWrapper` the size you want it and set `postion:relative`. Then size `.waterLevel` to fill the wrapper and set to `position:absolute`.

Now you can simply loop through and hide/show each div as needed.

Comment: I don't think you can animate the display property, instead use `opacity` which can be animated to make it look like it's fading in and out. For simple animation add `transition: all 1s;`

Comment: Right. `display` will only hide/show it. I would use a combination of `display`, `transition`, `opacity`, and `z-index` to get it to fade as intended.

Answer (score -2):

preload the background image first.

```
// put this in a javascript file, preferably before the closing </body> tag.
(function(){
    var imgPathArr = ["/path/to/image.jpg","/path/to/another/image.jpg"], i, img;
    for (i = 0; i < imgPathArr.length; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = imgPathArr[i];
    }
})();
```

Now, when you switch classes, it should be instant because it no longer has to download the image to do the swap.

Comment: Although the images are preloaded, blinks still exist.